# html layout -- horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have created a layout, which i need. In this layout i want the top row with images to scroll. I was not able to add this property in a single table.

So i created two tables upper one with only one row which will be scrolling. And bottom table will contain the two rows which will not scroll .

Two problems :--
1> I have added the scroll property to the div of above table but it shows for both the table. I want scrolling for only top table.
2> Also GUI is only covering the half the webpage (how to make it cover full height of the web page).

Please suggest on this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>

div.scrollable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

</style>

<body>


<div class=scrollable>
<table >
  <tr>

    <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#CC99FF; white-space:nowrap;">

    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" /> 

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />


<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

    </td>
  </tr>
</div>


</table>





<div>

<table width="100%"  border="0">

  <tr valign="top">
    <td style="background-color:#FFCCFF;
                  width:100px;text-align:top;">
      <b>Main Menu</b><br />
      BUTTON-1<br />
      BUTTON-2<br />
      BUTTON-3
    </td>

    <td style="background-color:#eeeeee;height:200px;
                  width:300px;text-align:top;">
        Table center
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#CC99FF;">
        <center>
      Copyright © 2014 My First Layout
        </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason you are using tables for this?

Comment: then what to use .. ? i refered this tutorial .. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp

Comment: On that site it even says `Using <table> to create a nice layout is NOT the correct use of the element. The purpose of the <table> element is to display tabular data!`. I would recommend using `div` etc...

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you have a wrong nesting for div and the table:

```
<div class=scrollable>
<table >
...
</div>
</table>
```

Secondly, div inside a table doesn't make any sense. Put it inside your inner td cell:

```
<table>
<tr><td>
<div>
...
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thirdly, you have a `colspan` attribute in your td from the first table, but there is only one cell in the table. This should be removed.

And finally, the main reason why this is not working is because you have a div that has the size of 100% of a container cell, which has no maximum width, so everything expands accordingly because no condition is met to stop it.

The solution is:
Use the `max-width` with a fixed value for a cell with images:

```
<td style="max-width:1024px; background-color:#CC99FF; white-space:nowrap;">
```

Comment: first answer is working ... you second option will never work.. i have tried it before.

Comment: Div not being in a cell but somewhere else in the table breaks your layout almost always. Check this article: http://css-tricks.com/using-divs-inside-tables/

Comment: no i tried this before it is not working .. can you show on .... http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Katoch The first way is wrong, do **not** use it like this. This isn't one of them "Oh it seems to work so its all good", nope. Its invalid and it would just cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Manage your Html div Structure:

```
input[type="image"]{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: what is advantage of adding this inside my Div structure .. id did not see any difference.